# Reverting to VM snapshot for multiple VMs

Tags: powershell, vmware, snapshot, revert, vsphere

```
#Connect-VIServer 10.222.111.21 –User root –Password Welcome2world

$VMs = Get-Content 'C:\vmscripts\vmlist.txt'

$snapname = 'BaseOS'

Get-Snapshot -VM $VMs -Name $snapname | Foreach-Object {  Set-VM -VM $_.VM -Confirm:$false }
```

The above script works fine as VM-snapshot exists. But it fails if any one of the VM's does NOT have the snapshot "BaseOs'.

Can someone help please! The platform is VMWARE.

Comment: Please edit the question. It is missing important details, like virtualization platform used (it *looks* like VMWare, but why should one guess?) and exact error message.

Comment: Sorry for missing the details... yes its VMWARE. Am guessing that TRY and CATCH should solve the issue. But not sure where to add the TRY/CATCH statement

Comment: What does fail mean here? Are you getting an error? That should be included.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how vMware Get-Snapshot cmd-let works. If you specify -Name parameter of snapshot and -VM as multiple hosts, it will fail if some of these hosts doe snot have the snapshot specified in -Name parameter. This will work:
Add some logic to your command to go through each $VM and if snapshot name equals $snapname, revert then. This will work:

```
$VMs = Get-Content 'C:\vmscripts\vmlist.txt'
$snapname = 'BaseOS';
foreach($VM in $VMs) { Get-Snapshot -VM $VM | Foreach-Object { if($_.Name -eq $snapname) { Set-VM -VM $VM -SnapShot $snapname -Confirm:$false } } }
```

Comment: Thank s for the clarification